# Java Servlet send form data to REST API

Tags: java, rest, post, servlets

I have a simple HTML form to send a request to a REST API.  It works well, when I submit, it sends the form data to API and displays the response in the browser.

```
<form name="theForm" action="localhost:8080/App/rest/consumeForm" method="post">
    <input name="userName" value="Bob Smith" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Browser shows:

```
{"address": "12 First St.", "city": "Toronto"}
```

I would like to capture the response.  Any ideas?  (no ajax or javascript, just plain old Servlet or JSP please)

**PART 2:**
I now POST my form to a servlet I created, which handles the request and response from the REST API.  It works nicely, but it needs the form data URLEncoded.  Anyone know if there is a way to convert form data to such a string, or even convert form data to JSON directly?

```
String charset = java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name();
String userName = "Bob Smith";
String country = "Canada";

String queryString = String.format("userName=%s&country=%s" 
        ,URLEncoder.encode(userName, charset) 
        ,URLEncoder.encode(country, charset)            
        );
```

**Can I build the above queryString dynamically?**

```
//// send request
URLConnection connection = new URL("localhost:8080/App/rest/consumeForm").openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true); // Triggers POST.
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + charset);
try (OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream()) {
    output.write(queryString.getBytes(charset));
}       

//// get response
BufferedReader apiResponse = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((connection.getInputStream())));
String output;
System.out.println("\n\n\nrecieved....");
while ((output = apiResponse.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that submitting to a servlet using POST and communicating with the REST API using the servlet works for me.  There may be better ways, but this seems relatively clean for junior developers to follow and maintain.  (I'm still open to other options).

I build a queryString with the form data (req is the HttpServletRequest)

```
String theQueryString="domainId=1";
for(Entry<String, String[]> qsParm:req.getParameterMap().entrySet()) {
  theQueryString+="&"+qsParm.getKey()+"="+URLEncoder.encode(req.getParameter(qsParm.getKey()), charset);   
}
```

```
// set up connection to use as API interaction
URLConnection connection = new URL("localhost:8080/App/rest/consumeForm").openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true); // Triggers POST apparently
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
        
// send request to API via connection OutputStream
try (OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream()) {
  output.write(theQueryString.getBytes(java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));  // this sends the request to the API url
}       

// get response from connection InputStream and read as JSON
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonMap = mapper.readTree(connection.getInputStream());

// now the response can be worked with in at least two ways that I have tried
String user1 = jsonMap.get("userName").asText();
String user2 = jsonMap.at("user").getValueAsText();
```

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to capture the response. Any ideas?

Install a servlet [`Filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) that handles this.  When it receives a request for the REST API endpoint, it can feed an [`HttpServletResponse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) to the next element in the chain that is equipped with any tooling you want.  You would probably find [`HttpServletResponseWrapper`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html) to be a useful base class for your custom-tooled response class.

The `Filter` implementation might be along these lines:

```
public class ResponseCapturingFilter implements Filter {
    private static final String SERVLET_TO_FILTER = "...";

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (((HttpServletRequest) request).getServletPath().equals(SERVLET_TO_FILTER)) {
            response = new MyCapturingResponseWrapper(response);
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

To capture the response text, you would want your wrapper to override at least `getOutputStream()` and `getWriter()` appropriately.

Comment: Thank you John.  My experience with filters has not been great, and I would like this process to be as simple as possible.  You have a great example, but with my limited knowledge I was not able to implement.

Comment: Well, @Jakev1, if the user is issuing a request directly to the REST API then the only way to capture the response in flight is to insert a component into the response path. If you want to do that inside your web application then a `Filter` is the only component that fits the role.  The alternatives I see are to modify the REST endpoint to feed you the response data directly (so not "in flight") or to stand up something in front of and outside the webapp.